# Read YouTube comment feed using Java

Tags: java, api, rss, youtube-api

I am want to read and display top 200 comments on a video on youtube. Basically when I go to the link: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EokUNzGJBI8/comments I get all the comments in rss feed form. How do I parse and read all the comments?
Edit: I have tried the same in php and it's quite easy to retrieve. I need to do it in Java and I am new to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the following steps in code:

1. Load that API in Java - make the call by [Downloading the Contents of that Page](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/196.html)
2. Parse the XML using a [Java XML Parser](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)
3. Loop through the comments and do what you will.